# JavaScript, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I want to have every facebook like registered when clicked and pass postID variable to MySQL query through JavaScript, but my code seems not working. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, please help me if you can.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="facebookdiv" onClick="addLike(1);"/>

</body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
function alertSmth(smth){
  alert(smth);
}

function addLike(postID){
  $.post('facebookLikeDB.php', {
    query: 'addLike',
    postID: postID
  });

  alert(postID);
}
```

facebookLikeDB.php

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypasswordhere') or die ("Couldn't connect with DB: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('sah_tests', $link) or die ("Couldn't select DB: " . mysql_error());

$queries = array(
  'addLike' => 'UPDATE facebook_like SET likes = 1 WHERE postID = ?'
);

$statement = $link->prepare($queries[$_POST['query']);
$statement->bind_param('s', $_POST['postID']);
$statement->execute();

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: dont use mysql! its deprecated

Comment: Yeah i know, but for now I'm just testing things.

Comment: Is this a mixup between `mysql_` and `PDO` ???

Comment: `$link->prepare` is PDO, not for the `mysql` module. Just use PDO.

Comment: Well yeah, I'm stupid, just fixed it by making the PDO stuff :P.

Comment: You code is not clean, plus why are you binding 's'?

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing ] in your facebookLikeDB.php on line 13

It should be

```
$statement = $link->prepare($queries[$_POST['query']]);
```

Comment: and `UPDATE facebook_like SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE postID = ?`